# App with ListView won´t start. Showing no errors

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore

I created an app with Flutter that contains a ListView that i build up with a StreamBuilder working with Firestore.
The code is written cleanly and ready to go but as soon as i run the app on my device, it tells me that " [The app] has been ended."

Android Studio doesnt really give out an error message. Within my logcat it tells me "Please configure Android SDK". Unfortunately i dont know how to proceed from here.

I made the Google Services setup step by step and the app is registered for Firestore usage.

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'Flutter Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.purple,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();

}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {

  // ignore: non_constant_identifier_names
  Stream<QuerySnapshot> tours_collection;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tours_collection = Firestore.instance.collection('tours_collection').snapshots();
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text("ToursList"),
      ),
      body: new ToursList(),
    );
  }
}

class ToursList extends StatelessWidget {

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new StreamBuilder(
      stream: Firestore.instance.collection('tours_collection').snapshots(),
      builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
        if (!snapshot.hasData) return new Text('Loading...');
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data.documents.map((document) {
            return new ListTile(
              title: new Text(document['name']),
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      },
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: If the app crashes there should typically be a stack trace in the logging output that shows why it crashes. That is really helpful in determining where the problem comes from.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen My logcat tells me that i have to configure the Android SDK. If i click on that, it opens my project structure. While my device is connected it also tells me that i have no connected devices although Android Studio shows the device in the toolbar.

Comment: Please include the exact error message and stack trace in your question, as they might make someone realize what you're getting. My first question would be whether you have a `FirebaseApp.configure(...)` statement anywhere.